# Max/Msp/Jitter - Get video to stop looping and return to neutral state?

Tags: max-msp-jitter

I need help!

I'm trying to have a video looping without stop(so that's the neutral state), and then when a sensor(a bang) is "activated" i want another video to start. when the new video has run once, i want to return to the first video that's looping(the neutral state).

I have gotten the second video to start playing instead of the neutral one when a bang has been sent, but i can't get it to return to the neutral state. (the toggle won't turn off automatically, the new video just loops and loops).

It's quite hard to explain but really thankful for any help.

Here's what i've got going so far:
http://postimg.org/image/3vmnp405n/

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of reorganizing, your patch looks like this (copy the block of gibberish below and then in max, click menu->file->new from clipboard. this is how max code is passed around):

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
605.3oc2W1rbaBCDG+L9oPiNSYPhOhcO01WiNc7HaTcjGPBKD1tMSd2qzB1w
IMN1k.LN8BLZkX0+8mVoU7vDO7B0ddEF8Yz2QddOLwyCL4L3011CWv1uLmUA
CCK46TKVi8a5xv2a.yaJ3FsBQOzgp1jyMleUxabNdAStBi9Qa2x5BgzN.vmz
VikLyx6ExUy07kllOKdVPnOJJI08JIx8jLMH7ne9oRZpD+FlDRns6ituQ.f+
IsVEYfTsx+SjT7IdPxJ.Of+pVvxQeSkmgc893jItG9uOzrVXB1XBJTaEbzWp
khM0bD4rfxN74ELiVrG6ivmAYjKgr3PB.KxcciYzWgYIiKy1IjYpcucB06gP
QwPR0r9CPw+2lTQANLHYUQiGzFnCoZgy.bJEc.XSAuphsh+WvQyYYmEL+6Pg
DRAnLMAdQCRrPIsOfB4iKTnIz.ZxfPkvQjJUFl1zm4JTXOSDIpmoxzQEJpx9
jIoyFFlLD27YQswnjc4X0KVlldGrUgFd34o94siz3tDJF0pU4GWcKYZKgLb8
btjsHGBnvyElBooqQYDcVWiR5Ggn7PIxtGljSCS3yv4B4K+2EXpc1edrWop0
KOD.MoF9nml7LdkQHYFgMG9owj9rwbuHKiKOkLYhJGr.IF9pqA8oZlNZpwUJ
4hxwcssQROSusjS5skbHWibnimbn2X34pVtRFM8bU3Y7N4gPtsvyKlpynm3w
SOQ2V54ZpTz0M6MEUYkka45pVWBBwd0g0JsqYpOzTHaZBkos+izVwgweGXgo
s0+M1h+05laWtO0cWL6773j+.fb.0xK
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Much easier to see what's going on right? Some fiddling got me to this:

```
----------begin_max5_patcher----------
1379.3ocyYs0bqZCD9YmeE6vKscFWFD2LzmNsu0eCMm4LxFYak.Rb.QbbOy4
+dWIAN1I9ZCPxK3Hgzd4a28iUJ+3tINykOypcf+.9GXxjeb2jIlozSLoc7Dm
B5yKxo0lk4rPVTvDJmo12oXOqLyyWBp0L3dmULkpht3wrlJphKEPASsVlcuC
jIY0fPpfMxpGA7MakMU.JvxFEqBnhL8LPFaAOiAJI7HiUZjZIUsXMPqAtB30
SMKaM8IyhPiA2rdU6znboUzExm3L3W4nMvyy40rERQFJDAtM8F1xxykaPElS
2Bx4OvVn9MnfJZn44agkxJf8DqZKjwWtjUgJBVxyYtPwV3IzDknMTVxDrLsc
LmAjBheMjKEqlB0R3us1F95Y9dddtcXVNWfVRiv.bD+1YEMEbQNSYfYR6jKq
VMWO1y0qcFCTvEq9VEZs1.WThO9ZfPBM+DY+IdlqG70N4HEpZ9+xrZbmvPcJ
aTcJsaVdlIhh.xuGk5rmDDzBiDb9yJNM2Q+hed2c5GSemYO5ngphuZEFJsAB
DpqpUPMSGwzuFs04521fo.pZ.W7ZEXsdDswjNDTroA5v4ufahWv.cru18dgc
4zk1bEJtkinRqxnvbJJpNEYsiNE0tiCzkKbzHa76NvF3kpCk9wDSDM0DXS5k
3Z73DWaYErT.l59ZKx+.W49ckqsBsE92fEoZfFoCPdjCIQDH+wl0XwDHPFfC
K2eU8MFs2vfJTPLSnF0dcMcEapI9pibRAVdeuCJyo6kZMEZoENLq33ksyd+A
2jXW+nWJawg5ePdhdH7F1ugWAaCJ12V01BTyAd26r1kZaIy5kN5ZIDlc3Zb6
qmC0NBFQhRcmEsqBHZlEoNEB4cBDx+HHj+oQH3uj4Y8HL0lJte97IgKMTcBb
x+x4R9AsIQ98GPQF.fpsh7MH0q6c3zvzMCQ9IQ6CQIo1ORdqHD4sHTX5.fPm
hPsQfsknZDTEKe6zSzxExU1x39lVtvVW5Z3ZJL27INMepVW3FwVUPxTsPqXl
NdVvP1TjDmakPcWWaHKdEqihUu5LTrUYcLnmvjLAc.c7ghSsiunkS0ukZsW3
TCSFENUaynlFFOOm54q.VHykU1k64lDNEeFGj3EOS+WdAAjPMLsGrbN1WaiG
w+OYeOVIi+HRpTqjkcSVVwvl.TlTx87zYgtneFLS6BP2icdYOv9DEaTPXfV1
A95A8B2SvrQEHoUpKfjAAFV1ADJIVd7A.KSFuVBNn82uzH3euAO9H7EZiRZf
YvC9RtTVBdWGfG5Gdc.Np4uUPwN2d9LsZPtL7mZXC78C5sNMBRGwb4JFM6BH
abKx5kLToxgsXYBomSkC89nnE5iN0hFrJbx3VgugKxjat3Qit8hvNHJzOxbt
nzdqHjD9olDr2oy1kr0+7YjfOH9rd7zR8O0DYHnlvCxnNyoEOS+xjK0ylejg
42e2y8kyEXg22ULaybdmWcc6FMqm+P+qFOk0hNGn6FKfWzdFqVwE1SI+xhBO
bQq4YYLw9GnIiWSmmyLFo2QQ5axdHWi8PFG6gbE3Sz3gO5x+KhOuxneq8Tvy
JkbgpMoILNwbjr118h7hO1P+.S1ZPZzKCewP5MOTewGWDwMvvM3g5CapM5f3
D6ceu2vgvGtBWH3FCRwlaXJHH5.GPO7ixAlMZY8g8AI0gWdgosa+Phm8tKRC
8s2mQ5PflWCIq9fh2R9.IN09wThMktMgfLLYzAWUUY33kQ3cMPZ5nYOupX3i
2dR9jYOj9fUuG+Np2mL6IXHqursIRKKehUU2JSiofM79fkTz7+UF4XD1glFO
w9+eh2sdy8n6PqvFZUX2rMU1VreNV2PJpmed2+Al87DN
-----------end_max5_patcher-----------
```

Please use this way to show your code.
People won't look at it if they have to recreate your patch by hand.